# Show password while you are typing it on the "my account" login page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, password, account

Is there a way to not show the points while you are typing the password but show the letters/numbers of the password?

I would like to implement it in my "My account" page of woocommerce:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly disagree to show the **password as the user typing it**. 
You could instead implement a way to show the status of the field with a user action like a **user click** to show password or on **hover**.
The reason is that the user makes the decision to show the password. Also, improve the security as maybe the users are not alone when they typing it

Some examples are:
[image]
Code from **herdiansc**

```
//Place this plugin snippet into another file in your applicationb
(function ($) {
    $.toggleShowPassword = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            field: "#password",
            control: "#toggle_show_password",
        }, options);

        var control = $(settings.control);
        var field = $(settings.field)

        control.bind('click', function () {
            if (control.is(':checked')) {
                field.attr('type', 'text');
            } else {
                field.attr('type', 'password');
            }
        })
    };
}(jQuery));

//Here how to call above plugin from everywhere in your application document body
$.toggleShowPassword({
    field: '#test1',
    control: '#test2'
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/herdiansc/dnznh/8/)

And 
user **Baraka Mahili**

```
$('#show_password').hover(function functionName() {
                        //Change the attribute to text
                        $('#password').attr('type', 'text');
                        $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-eye-open').addClass('glyphicon-eye-close');
                    }, function () {
                        //Change the attribute back to password
                        $('#password').attr('type', 'password');
                        $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-eye-close').addClass('glyphicon-eye-open');
                    }
                );
https://codepen.io/GBMahili/pen/pEvVZP
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this, without making too many changes to the code, is to use JavaScript (jQuery) that will add Hide/Show capability to the existing password field.

Excellent free jQuery plugin for that is: [HideShowPassword](https://github.com/cloudfour/hideShowPassword). It has many ways to customize how the password will be visible.

Answer (score -1):

override by copying `woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-login.php`. it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php`.

and change password field attribute `type="password"` to `type="text"`

hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Never change the type of the field like this, because other parts of the code might depend on it. Also, it might cause security related problems.